# jQuery: code stops working after adding delay() and removeClass()

Tags: jquery

Here's my code...

```
 $('nav ul li').hover(function() {

    $(this).addClass('hoverIn');


  },
  function() {

    $(this).addClass('hoverOut');


  });
```

which works fine.

But when I add delay() and removeClass() it doesn't work, as follows...

```
 $('nav ul li').hover(function() {

    $(this).addClass('hoverIn').delay(800).removeClass('hoverIn');


  },
  function() {

    $(this).addClass('hoverOut').delay(800).removeClass('hoverOut');


  });
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have mentioned, `.removeClass()` is not an animation function so is unaffected by any queued effects.

The simplest solution is to use `.queue()` to insert your call into the animation queue:

```
$(this).addClass('hoverIn').delay(800).queue(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hoverIn').dequeue();
});
```

The `.dequeue()` call is important to ensure that any other queued operations still take place.

Note that using the animation queue also means that you can use `.stop()` to cancel the operation if it hasn't happened yet.  Using timers would make that a *lot* more complicated.

---

If you want to get really fancy, this plugin I just knocked out will allow you to add any *arbitrary* jQuery function into the animation queue:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.queued = function() {
        var self = this;
        var func = arguments[0];
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
        return this.queue(function() {
            $.fn[func].apply(self, args).dequeue();
        });
    }
}(jQuery));
```

with this, the line above would become:

```
$(this).addClass('hoverIn').delay(800).queued('removeClass', 'hoverIn');
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/h5nWw/

Comment: +'d this by being fast; simple; and my personal favorite: two lines of code are enough :)

Answer (score 5):

`.delay()` only works with jQuery methods that use the animation queue, thus is does not work with `removeClass()`.

The `removeClass()` operation will still be performed, but it will be performed immediately, not after the delay time.

So, when you do:

```
$(this).addClass('hoverIn').delay(800).removeClass('hoverIn');
```

that is the same as:

```
$(this).addClass('hoverIn').removeClass('hoverIn');
```

which is the same as doing nothing, thus you see not effect.

---

You can solve your problem with `setTimeout()` like this:

```
 $('nav ul li').hover(function() {
    var self = $(this).addClass('hoverIn');
    setTimeout(function() {self.removeClass('hoverIn');}, 800);
  }, function() {
    var self = $(this).addClass('hoverOut');
    setTimeout(function() {self.removeClass('hoverOut');}, 800);
  });
```

---

Or, using a common function, like this:

```
jQuery.fn.addClassTemporary = function(cls, t) {
    var self = this.addClass(cls);
    setTimeout(function() {self.removeClass(cls);}, t);
}

 $('nav ul li').hover(function() {
     $(this).addClassTemporary('hoverIn', 800);
 }, function() {
     $(this).addClassTemporary('hoverOut', 800);
 });
```

Comment: +'d, a custom function, nice :)

Comment: IMHO this is unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @Alnitak - and your queue, dequeue custom function is less complicated? Hardly.  Either can work, but I'd be surprised if folks thought your solution was less complicated than this one.

Comment: @jfriend00 I was referring to your use of `setTimeout` versus `.queue`, which IMHO is the right way to run something in sequence with an animation.  The jQuery plugin came later...

Answer (score 1):

jQuery .delay() applies to the animation queue, it does not serve as a timer like setTimeout does...

To your goal, I can suggest you to use the [hoverIntent plug-in](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html):

See this [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/Sq5qW/) Example! <sup>adjust the timeout to fit your needs</sup>

**jQuery**

```
$("nav ul li").hoverIntent({    
    sensitivity: 1, // number = sensitivity threshold (must be 1 or higher)    
    interval: 10,   // number = milliseconds for onMouseOver polling interval    
    timeout: 800,   // number = milliseconds delay before onMouseOut    
    over:function(){
        $(this).removeClass("hoverOut").toggleClass("hoverIn");
    },
    out: function(){
        $(this).removeClass("hoverIn").toggleClass("hoverOut");
    }
});
```